# Play gif on visibility

Tags: javascript, safari, gif

I have a gif on my page, initially is hidden with opacity : 0 and visibility : hidden (I can't use display:none here for others reasons).

```
<img src="xxx.gif" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
```

I display gif on click

```
$("#image").click(function(){$("#imageZ").css({"opacity":"1", "visibility":"visible"});});'
```

This code works. It display images. But I've a strange problem with no-repeat gif. On Chrome, it's ok, when gif display, it launch and I see what I want.

On Safari it doesn't work, I see anything. I think gif is already read and don't relaunch when visibility : visible.

It worked when I used display:block instead of visibility:visible. Visibility add it on DOM and works on Chrome so I don't understand why it doesn't works on Safari.

Do you know this problem and have you an idea to patch it ?

Thanks.

Comment: any updated on this?